# Images are missing when parsing a string to html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using "Feedzirra" to write a simple reader. When parsing a string to html in view, I use something like:

```
 <%= entry.summary.html_safe %>
```

The words are displayed, but the images seem missing. Anyone have ideas? Thanks. Here is the content of "entry.summary":

```
 "&#8220;We gotta post this one!&#8221; -MF All ye need do is ask, Cute Overlord, and eet shall be done. Posted on YT by Frisco68, who added &#8220;The weasel war dance is a colloquial term for a behavior of excited ferrets and weasels. In wild animals, it is speculated that this dance is used to confuse [...]<img alt=\"\" border=\"0\" src=\"http://stats.wordpress.com/b.gif host=cuteoverload.com&#038;blog=41949&#038;post=100838&#038;subd=cuteoverload&#038;ref=&#038;feed=1\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" />"
```

Comment: And you're sure it's a valid image URL? E.g., you've tried to retrieve it via curl or similar?

Comment: No, I don't. Actually, I don't how to use curl (new to web dev)...But I have tried a couple of feeds, and only words are showed.

Comment: Check your browser's net requests to see if there's (a) a GET request to the image URL, and (b) that it worked.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for your help. It turns out the image is too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERm, I check the picture url, it actually just 1 X 1 size, or it actually display and you can't see that?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that. I change entry.summary to entry.content and the image is displayed. I should have read the picture url more careful.  1 X 1 is too small!

Comment: ya,I can't see that as well :P